# Building a Comic strip RSS reader - feeds won't show

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, rss, windows-store-apps

I went through [this guy's tutorial](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/RSS-Reader-affe3358/sourcecode?fileId=59460&pathId=255968998) to build an RSS reader in the hopes of converting it to a comic strip reader, but when I try to do so, the app never works the way I want it to.

The app in it's current state has an item's page with items that lead to a split page which displays blogs from the feed the tutorial provides, but when I try and use [my own feeds](http://dilbert.com/rss/) the app displays an empty items page tile and the split page behind it shows nothing but "Author, pub date, link, categories" stacked in the centre of the screen.

What I want to have happen is to have the app launch to the split screen directly and display [these comic strips](http://dilbert.com/rss/), but I'm not sure how to make it happen...

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be fetching data from wrong RSS URL. Follow these steps

1. Download this [blog reader sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Getting-started-with-C-and-41e15af5/sourcecode?fileId=63881&pathId=1578101521)
2. That link will open `FeedData.cs` file. See that & do the changes in downloaded project. Go to `GetFeedsAsync()` method definition. It contains all the RSS channels.
3. Replace all `http://blogs.windows.com/bla-bla-bla` RSS URLs with theses URLs.

   - Most Popular : http://feed.dilbert.com/dilbert/most_popular
   - Strips : http://feed.dilbert.com/dilbert/daily_strip
   - Blog : http://feed.dilbert.com/dilbert/blog
   - Mashup : http://feed.dilbert.com/dilbert/mashups
4. That's it. Now run the app, by selecting `WindowsBlogReader` project as startup project.